# Is it possible to deserialize a raw string directly into a specific type?

Tags: rust, serde

I've searched a bit and can't seem to find an answer for this, so this is probably a duplicate.

I have a `String` like this (the actual strings are not literals):

```rust
let param_type_raw = String::from("address");
```

I want to deserialize it into the type `ethabi::ParamType`, which implements the `Deserializer` trait. So far, I've came up with this:

```rust
let param_type: ParamType = serde_json::from_str(format!("\"{}\"", param_type_raw).as_str())?;
```

However, it seems extremely redundant to convert the string into a JSON string just to deserialize it into `ParamType`. I'm certain there must be a better way of just deserializing a `String` by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [specific function for that](https://docs.rs/ethabi/latest/ethabi/param_type/struct.Reader.html#method.read):

```rust
use ethabi::{param_type::Reader, ParamType};

fn main() {
    let param_type_raw = String::from("address");

    let param_type: ParamType = Reader::read(&param_type_raw).unwrap();
    println!("{:?}", param_type);
}
```

```
Address
```

Answer (score 2):

Answering the title more generally: There is a suite of deserializers available for each of the primitive types in the [`serde::de::value`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/value/index.html) module that can be created with `.into_deserializer()` provided by the [`IntoDeserializer`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.IntoDeserializer.html) trait.

So if you have a string and you know your type can be deserialized from a string, you can do this:

```
use ethabi::ParamType;
use serde::de::value::Error;
use serde::de::{Deserialize, IntoDeserializer};

fn main() {
    let param_type_raw = "address";
    let param_type: Result<_, Error> = ParamType::deserialize(param_type_raw.into_deserializer());
    println!("{:?}", param_type);
}
```

```
Ok(Address)
```

Slightly annoying since the deserializers are generic over the error type, so you have to specify one somewhere, but that's what [`serde::de::value::Error`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/value/struct.Error.html) is for.

Answer (score 1):

```rust
let param_type_raw = "address";
let mode: ParamType = serde_json::from_str(&format!(r#"{}"#, param_type_raw)).unwrap();
```

Or

```
let param_type_raw = "address";
let mode: ParamType = serde_json::from_str(&format!("\"{}\"", param_type_raw)).unwrap();
```